# Django - How to simplify the create new row of a table with many foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is the sample model:

```
class GenderDecode(models.Model):
    gender_code = models.IntegerField(primary_key= True)
    gender_explain = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class AgeDecode(models.Model):
    age_code = models.IntegerField(primary_key= True)
    age_explain = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age_group = models.ForeignKey(AgeDecode, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    gender_group = models.ForeignKey(GenderDecode, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

The initial setup of two tables `GenderDecode` and `AgeDecode`:

**GenderDecode**

```
gender_code    gender_explain
     1              male
     2             female
```

**AgeDecode**

```
age_code    age_explain
   1           young
   2            old
```

Provided I want to create a new user - John Male Young. I have to do this.

```
User(name = 'John', 
     age_group = AgeDecode.objects.filter(gender_code=1).first(), 
     gender_group = GenderDecode.objects.filter(age_code=1).first()
).save()
```

I want to do this

```
User(name = 'John', 
     age_group = 1, 
     gender_group = 1
).save()
```

But I got this error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "User.gender_group" must be a "GenderDecode" instance.
```

Well, if the above syntax is a must, is there any way to go around to simplify my new row code ?

Comment: Are you sure the `gender_code=1` and the `age_code=1` exists? Or you have to validate it before save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_id`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) of the foreign key field like this:

```
User(
     name='John', 
     age_group_id=1, 
     gender_group_id=1
).save()
```

Comment: Hardcoding the data is not good option, I think the big problem in this approach is that you don't have a form andyour input is not validated.

Comment: Yes that's true. But the question in this case is if it's possible to do it.

Comment: Can you guys hint me a better approach ? I been look up `form` of django but still not quite understand what you mean @allexiusw

Comment: You can use forms to process user input. Like in your case, you can build a form that accepts a name, an age group id, and a gender group id. And then let the form build the object for you. The form will also support validating your user input, and all sorts of other stuff. You can read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/).